# How to handle copy_from_user array bound violation?

Tags: c, archlinux, system-calls

I am implementing a custom syscall in arch linux, and I need to pass a string to and the size of the string to the syscall so that the syscall could do `copy_from_user()` to copy the string to the kernel space.

However, **the problem is that I want to handle the case when user specifies size to be way bigger than the actual size of the string that needs to be stored in the kernel space.** Because I want to prevent **array bound violation**.

I checked the source code of the `copy_from_user()` and it doesn't seem like trying to handle that situation at all.

How am I supposed to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: copy_from_user will handle it. It will return 0 on success or number of bytes it couldn't copy on failure.

Comment: @AlanAu Do you mean if I am trying to copy 32 bytes from a 16 bytes string, the `copy_from_user()` function would actually return 16?

Comment: Yes that's right. Assuming that the 16 bytes after your string are not valid user memory (because it is a memcpy not a strncpy so it doesn't care about null terminators, only the length).

Comment: Just noticed you specifcally mentioned "strings" in your question. So just wanted to emphasise that copy_to_user is not a string function. So it will happily copy past any null terminator if you tell it to. For example, if you have a char array of size 16 and you put an empty string in there and then do copy_to_user with len 16, it will copy the entire 16 bytes (not just stop at the empty string). Just in case that's not clear.

Comment: @AlanAu Hi, I had a try, and I am pretty sure if `copy_from_user()` is trying to copy 32 bytes from a16 bytes string, it will success and won't give me error.

Comment: @AlanAu That is my problem, I want to prevent this kind of situation, and I am not sure if there is any.

Comment: Why do you care if it copies more? copy_to_user ensures you don't access invalid memory. But if the memory is valid it's generally not harmful to copy the entire block. Even if it goes past the end of the string. After the copy you have the string terminator so any processing after the copy knows where the string ends and can act accordingly. So just trying to understand what your use case is.

Comment: If you really want to stop at the string terminator then you can copy one byte at a time and stop if copy_to_user fails or terminator is encountered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74978/discussion-between-alan-au-and-jialun-liu).